# VB.net simple license key to protect application

Tags: vb.net, license-key

I working on a simple vb application. But I want to protect it to give the user the option to use it only for a specific time.
So I was thinking to make a text file with a key-code (Beside Random characters, it contains an expire date). When the application is started after this expire date, the application should close automatically.
The location where this textile is location can be the same location where the executable is running from.
Does somebody of you have a good idea how to implement it? Or is there a easier way how to implement this

Comment: Note that if the software is running in user-controlled hardware, it's **always** possible to bypass whatever protection you may implement.

Comment: @Alejandro is right of course, but a more constructive way to look at it is to ask yourself the question 'Who am I up against?' - if your users are technically illiterate, even the mechanism you describe will be beyond them.  Certainly even a small technical advance beyond this level will keep out all but the most determined, if the application is not particularly popular, or expensive, or tempting in some other way.

Comment: By its nature there is no such thing as a `simple license key`.  You cannot keep something secret on the users system.  You *can* create a key (file) in a manner that makes it very, very hard to reproduce other than on *your* system.  Then the client app "just" has to verify the license.  Still all it takes is them to patch your code to `IsRegistered = True` rather than call the method.  Expirys are a whole other level of concern.  The first question you should ask yourself is `why does it expire`? Unless you have a tech support crew, why do you deserve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give a "Trial period" to your application you might want rather hard-code that to prevent tampering. Then, when purchased make a modification to registry and different files (maybe downloads a few files that "register" the application so that it recognizes itself as "full". To go one step further maybe periodically have the application reach out to your server and verify the license.

This is a huge subject that a lot of smarter people than me can weigh in on. I will note that this is part of a constant battle between developers and hackers trying to get around licensure.

Answer (score 1):

To make software unlocked for some period of time, you can create text file on websites like [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and add them an expiry date. Then make your software check if file is still valid.

Note that users can "track down" requests your software sends, **never** store your private information linked with your software.

You can also use [HWID protection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBe-gQiO-dA) which ensures your software will work only if it matches hardware information stored in encrypted string.

*You can hash other user's information like username, wifi name and so on, but remember that changing any of this information (OS, hardware or system information) will create new unique HWID, which may not match the previous one - resulting in failed HWID authorization.*

To make bypassing protection harder, you can [obfuscate your software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)).